# In MacOS, Unity Editor will crash when I open a Unity project with an error "No git found"

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I found some articles that solved the title issue but I can not find out the issue solver for MacOS.

My environment.

- MacOS
- Unity 2020.3.30f1
- Installed a git client (this client is provided by Apple that is installed with Xcode command line tools)

I am so wondered why I get the error because I was able to use a Unity editor with Git previously.

I am being getting the error suddenly. I am not sure when the editor started being crash.

Comment: _"...Unity Editor will crash...with an error 'No git found'"_ - that's strange because Unity has [no built-in support for Git](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Versioncontrolintegration.html), only _Perforce_ and _Plastic_.   Perhaps you mean _some other client_ is responsible for the crash?  You can [configure](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExternalVersionControlSystemSupport.html) Unity for **external** version control however Unity in no way performs Git operations proper in such a mode.

Answer (score 0):

"No Git found" does not necessarily mean Git is not installed.

It can also mean your Unity Editor does not find a local Git repository in the folder it is set for its project.

As [mentioned here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/ttfahk/comment/i2yb8lj/?context=3), as an example for a project stored on GitHub (you could use another third-party Git repository hosting service though):

> - create a GitHub account. Make sure you have 2fa set up
> - install GitHub desktop
> - Make sure that in unity `edit -> project settings`, under "`editor`" you have "`Asset Serialization Mode`" set to "`Force Text`";
>   and under "`Version Control`" it is set to `Visible Meta Files`. (If needed, further instructions here: "[How to set up a Unity project in GitHub](https://unityatscale.com/unity-version-control-guide/how-to-setup-unity-project-on-github/)")
> - Go to GitHub desktop and go to `file -> add local repository`.
>   It will say **no git found**, would you like to create one.
> - Don’t add the gitignore they suggest
> - Make sure it’s set to private and say yes.
> - Put the [Unity gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore) in the root folder:
>   Note that the `asset`, `library`, etc folders need to be at the same level as the `.gitignore` file.
>   So you have `.gitignore`, other files, the `asset` folder, the `library` folder, etc. all together.
>   By default unity will create a new folder and you’ll have e.g. `folder 1/folder 2/assets` etc. If gitignore is in `folder 1` it will create problems.
>   With a blank project with no `.gitignore`, GitHub desktop will want to commit 20k files. With the `.gitignore` it will be about 30.
> - Commit via GitHub desktop

Comment: Thank you for the comment but my problem is not like that. I know the local git repository and I can use repositories to store my projects. I also can open a Unity project but now I can't on my Mac. This is why I'm wondered. Why I can't open the Unity project that I was able to open previously.

And I have other issue. I can't open a new project that is just created from Unity Hub.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good at English. I mean I can open specific my project on my Mac previously but now I can't open the project on my Mac anymore. Of cause my mac that I said is same. I add top of that the crash problem and 'No git found' error are started same time I think.

Comment: @HirumaKazuya Maybe the Git client has changed? Can yo try and create a new Unity project, as a Git repository (following my answer) to check if Unity can open that new Git-managed project?

Comment: I'm not sure that the Git client has changed or not but I didn't change the client. (I also installed some tools then these tools can change the path or something I think)  I tried to create a new Unity project but the project is always crashed. Other words, I can't open a new Unity project anymore.

Comment: @HirumaKazuya Can you try and uninstall/reinstall Unity itself?

Comment: I've tried to uninstall / reinstall but I still get errors. (crash)

Comment: @HirumaKazuya Can you try and create/load a new Git repository Unity project in a completely different part of your folders, just to rule out some side effect with other Git repositories?

Comment: I tried to clone a new Unity project that was my previous project and opened it. I can open it but I get still same git error. Actual error is here "An error occurred while resolving packages:  Project has invalid dependencies:    com.cysharp.unitask: No 'git' executable was found. Please install Git on your system then restart Unity and Unity Hub."

Comment: And I'm wondered if I select an ARFoundation package in a package manager window then the editor will crash. Bug reporter tells me reasons. Here is the last of 
 the stack trace of the report. "TextRenderingPrivate::GetFontPaths(dynamic_array<core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, 0ul>&) + 431"